# Explanation of Specific Sequence from Maths Homework

Tags: sequences-and-series

As part of my homework, I have to find the next three terms in a sequence and explain my method. I am struggling to find the rule which links the terms:

```
1, 4, 13, 40, _, _, _
```

If anyone has any suggestions, it'd be very helpful - thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the differences between each term?

Comment: You are adding multiples of 3 (3,9,27)!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No wonder you're struggling! I'm sorry to say that this problem (at least as you've written it here) doesn't have an answer! Or, at least, it doesn't have a single, correct answer. You can make up your own, any way you'd like. The only criteria are, i think,

- There should be some rule governing how each element of the list appears
- The rule rule probably ought to give only one answer, so anyone reading that rule, anywhere and anywhen, as long as they understand it, should get the exact same sequence
- That rule shouldn't be broken by the start of the list (1, 4, 13, 40)
- The rule should be able to give at least three more terms (although it's probably meant to be possible to continue indefinitely)
- The next three terms you give should also follow this rule

Apart from that, you're free to pick whatever you want! If you manage to find a rule which gives the sequence $1, 4, 13, 40,-42,\pi, \sqrt 2$, then by all means, go for it.

That being said, there might be one specific rule that the problem authors *intend* you to find. I think that that's the one hinted at in the comments. That's also probably the easiest rule to follow, so you can go with that if you want.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful - I take it my teacher wrote it wrong

Comment: @FinnE The problem with these kinds of sequence "problems" is that if you want them to not be "puzzles" (i.e. if you want to avoid any guessing and mind reading), then you (very often) have to give so much information that they become too easy to be interesting. I don't think the teacher wrote it wrong, it's a nice puzzle. It just isn't a true math problem.

Comment: @FinnE Yes, your teacher asked an ambiguous question. Clearly what he or she _meant_ was to find "the rule that would first occur to anyone who had done many problems of this kind". For that, consider the successive differences (a natural thing to do) and think about powers of three Other comments point to this method. Then it's up to you to decide whether you want to discuss the ambiguity with your teacher.

Comment: I see - thanks for everyone's help